# how to use nodesdk install chaincode on fabric v2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I hope to create channels and install chaincodes in fabric v2.2. But node sdk no longer provides these functions in version 2.2. How can I achieve these functions using nodejs?

I found some examples of calling the system chaincode lscc, qscc to get some functions not provided by the SDK, such as querying the installed chaincode, block information, etc. Can I implement functions such as installing chaincode and adding channels in the same way? But I can't figure out how to format the parameters, is there some concrete example you can provide? or some other methods？
I tried to use java and go sdk, but their configuration is too cumbersome and there is no clear tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the `peer` CLI commands to drive configuration and chaincode deployment.

For a pure Node approach, there is a Fabric admin API here, although (at the time of writing) this is in a development state, not at a formal release version:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-admin-sdk/tree/main/node/admin

I'm not sure that code is published to the NPM registry for use, but you can certainly use it as a reference.

The chaincode deployment in particular uses transaction functions on the `_lifecycle` system chaincode. Some of the transaction functions (such as **InstallChaincode**) need to be evaluated on specific peers. Others can use any suitable endorsing peers, like a regular transaction submit or evaluate call. If you can understand Golang, there is an admin implementation in the same repository that uses the standard [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) for many of the chaincode lifecycle invocations:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-admin-sdk/tree/main/pkg/chaincode